# Tuning physics for a "worms"-like game

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm using LibGDX and Box2D for my physics but my characters bounce all over the place when moving and if there is a small slope in the terrain they launch off of it.
I've tried tweaking settings but it either seems to completely kill the motion or send the player off to space. How can I get movement closer to Worms where there is a little bounce but the players for the most part stick to the floor.

For reference I want it to be like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMDfo2czbu0&t=5s

What kind of things can I tweak to get that kind of motion?

Comment: To know what to change, it would help to know how you're doing it currently. What kinds of collision representations are you using, what code are you using to move your characters, what settings have you tried tweaking?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue was I was constantly applying velocity instead of doing it based on a delta. Now the player does not bounce around violently.

Comment: Showing a code sample might help other users experiencing similar problems.